# Excel Power Pivot: Match next non-blank item after date match for customer across two tables using DAX

Tags: excel, vba, dax, powerquery, powerpivot

I need to create a calculated column in **Table_Order** that would find the next matching, non-blank **Customer Status** on or after the current **Order Date** for the current row **Customer #**.

The tricky part is when there is no matching **Customer Status** in **Table_Ship** for a **Customer #** on a particular **Order Date** (please see the orange highlights). The match then needs to be on the next matching **Ship Date** for the **Customer #** where the **Customer Status** is not blank.

Please could somebody help me and show me the DAX?

I've spent a long time Googling and have gotten nowhere. I feel like this should be easy!

Also please bear in mind that these tables are massively simplified versions of my actual work, and any suggestion to reorganise the tables or start from scratch won't help me, I need some DAX please!

Thanks in advance!

Phil.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for trying to help me with this. I'm not sure where I'm supposed to enter the calculation to create a table? The only places I know to do it are in column headings and the formula bar (i.e. for measures). Is this different in Excel Power Pivot? If it is, apologies. I thought it all worked the same way.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you have large datasets, but I would recommend you create a FactCustomer table. Here there are the steps I followed with the data you provided.

1. Create a FactCustomer table

```
FactCustomer =
    DISTINCT ( Table_Ship[Customer #] )
```

2. Create a relationship between Table_Ship and FactCustomer and Table_Order and FactCustomer, using Customer # as key.

[image]

3. Create a calculation in Table_Order to find customer status. The calculation makes a lookup (similar to VLOOKUP in excel) to find customer with the same date. This would retrieve the blank for Customer #3, so is neccesary to create a second calculation that would scan Table_Ship for the minimum date without blanks. The final step is using an IF statement to treat blank in the first function, when they are blank, the second formula is used.

```
Customer Status = 
var find_customer = LOOKUPVALUE(Table_Ship[Customer Status],Table_Ship[Ship_Date],[Order Date],Table_Ship[Customer #],[Customer #])
var last_non_blank_date = CALCULATE(min(Table_Ship[Ship_Date]),Table_Ship[Customer Status]<>BLANK())
var find_non_blank = CALCULATE(min(Table_Ship[Customer Status]),filter(Table_Ship,Table_Ship[Ship_Date]=last_non_blank_date))

return if(ISBLANK(find_customer),find_non_blank,find_customer)
```

The result I get:

[image]